# Change a link text with Scriptaculous?

Tags: hyperlink, toggle, scriptaculous

I have a link which, when clicked, shows an image using Scriptaculous. When I click the link again, it hides the image again. Now, when the link is clicked, I call a function which is called toggle(). How can I change the links text when I click it and change it back to what it was when its clicked again? Thats my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle(element){
        new Effect.toggle(element, 'Slide', {duration:0.5});
    }

</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to pass the object being clicked into the function and check its innerHTML.

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('myDiv', this); return false">click this</a>
//replace my div with the name of the element to slide.

function toggle(element, obj){
  if(obj.innerHTML == 'click this'){
    obj.innerHTML = 'clicked';
  }
  else{
    obj.innerHTML = 'click this';
  }
  new Effect.toggle(element, 'Slide', {duration:0.5});
}
```

Comment: If you have HTML code in innerHTML like me, then you'd notice that in IE HTML code is in capital letters, so I would suggest lowering letters in if() sentence like this:        var togglePlusMinus = obj.innerHTML;
  if(togglePlusMinus.toLowerCase() == '<span>+</span>'){